# How to mirror Photoshop window to iPhone/iPad screen for mockup/development?

Tags: iphone, ipad, photoshop, mockups

Is it possible to live preview a photoshop document on an iPhone or iPad? I tried it with VNC, but it only transfers a limited range of colors which is suboptimal. Is this possible with Apple's Developer Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to this page with the same question. looked at the answer --> the app --> reviews and decided I'd use what I had to get it done. The results are awesome!

Requirements:
Iphone /Ipad App: Air Display ($9.99) 
Photoshop CS4+

1.) Download Air Display.

Air display is by far the best app out there for mirroring or creating an extra screen with your iOS device. I looked at all flavors of VNC/DNS. VNC is for screen sharing and the results don't exactly make you cheerful. Air Display uses your iOS device as an extra screen like your desktop setup. $9.99 is premium pricing but well worth it. There are many uses for the app after you buy it. Check out their site here:

http://avatron.com/apps/air-display

2.) Setup Air Display

These instructions are covered in the app. You'll end up with this sort of setup:
[image]

Take into account your hot corners.

3.) Create a mirrored window for your document

- Create a new window for your document.
  Menu Bar --> Window --> Arrange --> New Window For [Your Document]
  [image]

4.) Setup your window 
A new document tab will pop up with the same name as the original. Drag this tab to your extra screen and there you go. Mirrored photoshop on your iOS device!

Now this new window will mirror the document on your main screen. The great part is this new photoshop window can be set up with its own View attributes (guides, rulers, etc). Here's some more tips:

- You'll know your working with the right window when your in Photoshop and the main windows actions are greyed out. Now the menu bar will affect the mirrored window
  [image]
- Use These Settings:
  Full screen
  Fit on screen
  Actual Pixels
  [image]
- Turn Off Guides (CMD ;)
- Turn Off Rulers (CMD R)

There you go. An awesome mock up interface for Photoshop --> iPad

Answer (score 4):

Easier, free way that works both on windows and mac : https://itunes.apple.com/lv/app/ps-play-for-photoshop/id651937919?mt=8

PS Play - works with Photoshop's Remote Connections (Edit->Remote Connections). Just add your computer's IP address and the password configured in Photoshop and you're done.

Comment: Now it works:) the Photoshop's Remote Connections panel showed IPv4 address which I think was not right it started as 10.200.x.y, but when I used the local IP as 192.168.0.2 then the app connected successfully. ipconfig shows the details of the IP.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming across this question now, check out Skala Preview (link below). If you have CS5 or higher, it even allows for live previews. Only problem for me is it requires iOS 5 and OSX 10.7, and I'm quite happy on 10.6.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skala-preview/id498875079?mt=12

Answer (score 1):

The only way that this would work built in (that I am aware of) is if a UIWebView managed to open it. Otherwise I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could try manipulating a photo that is synced to the device then syncing the device with iTunes.

I'm more inclined to think that you would be better off writing an app specific to this task and just have it open the file over wifi or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with using a Photoshop action which saves a PNG to a web server. [Atomic Web Browser](http://atomicwebbrowser.com/) supports a full screen mode which then shows this PNG embedded in a HTML file which reloads once per second. It works good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You've tried the rest, now try the best!

Xscope is an app for mac & iphone.  Install it, and not only will it give you a bunch of useful tools, but one of those tools is called 'mirror'.

You simply:

1. Jump into **Photoshop** and go to **Edit / Remote Connections...** to set a password
2. Open **Xscope** on mac and put that same password in your **preferences**
3. Then in **Xscope**, click the **'Mirror'** button, then the **'Photoshop'** button (see http://d.pr/i/ziaC)
4. Open the **Xscope Mirror iPhone app** and press the button to connect to your mac

And that's it. You should then be able to see your canvas. The app also lets you scale the image larger or smaller based on ratios, and even take snapshots for later reference.

It's a pretty cool app. Promise to God I don't work for them!

http://xscopeapp.com/